# How to use the return of a lambda to update a state of a composable

Tags: kotlin, lambda, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable function with a textfield and a button

```
@Composable
private fun ButtonsColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    // enum class DataEntryInputState
    dataEntryInputState: DataEntryInputState = DataEntryInputState.Default,
    onClickParam: () -> Unit
) {
    // enum class ButtonType that change content of the button
    var buttonState by remember { mutableStateOf(ButtonType.Text) }
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        DataEntryInputLarge(
            ...
            // custom composable
            ...
        )
        ButtonPrimary(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable {
                    buttonState = ButtonType.Loading
                },
            text = "Login",
            enabled = textFieldState,
            type = buttonState,
            onClick = onClickParam
        )
    }
}
```

I want to update *buttonState* when onClick finish, something like:

```
onClickParam: () -> Boolean
...
        onClick = {
            if(!onClickParam){
                buttonState = DataEntryInputState.Default
            }
        }
```

It means that when the lambda function finishes if it's false update the content of the button according to what I already have. I don't sure if it's possible or if it's another way to do that.

Comment: You can do that for sure. You just need to call function `if(!onClickParam()){`, your current code shouldn't build. Also I suggest you not adding `clickable` modifier on `Button` because it may block the original gesture tracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just accept something for the lambda, for example, this updates a boolean value based on the current value

```
fun CustomComposable(
onClick: (Boolean) -> Boolean
){
var myBoolean by mutableStateOf (false)
myBoolean = onClick(myBoolean)
}
```

Now, the `onClick` parameter can be implemented something like this:

```
{ receivedBoolean -> //You can also use 'it' keyword to access this
return !receivedBoolean //Just return the complimentary boolean 
}
```

When implemented like this, your Composable is passing in a Boolean to the `onClick` which is returning the complimentary boolean, and hence, when this `onClick` is complete, thr value of `myBoolean` within the Composable will be flipped. This is achieved by simply adding a getter, by adding a value in the parenthesis of `onClick`, and a setter, implemented by returning a `Boolean` instead of `Unit`. This is just an example. Implement it the way you want. The method will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to create a mutable state in your parent composable like

`var dataEntryState by remember { mutableStateOf(DataEntryInputState.Default) }`

and call `ButtonsColumn` composable from it's paranet like

```
ButtonsColumn(modifier, dataEntryState) {
   // Update state after finishing lamba
   dataEntryState = DataEntryInputState.Default
}
```